# Average the duplicated values from two paired lists in Python

Tags: python, list

in my code I obtain two different lists from different sources, but I know they are in the same order. The first list ("names") contains a list of keys strings, while the second ("result_values") is a series of floats. I need to make the pair unique, but I can't use a dictionary as only the last value inserted would be kept: instead, I need to make an average (arithmetic mean) of the values that have a duplicate key.

Example of the wanted results:

```
names = ["pears", "apples", "pears", "bananas", "pears"]
result_values = [2, 1, 4, 8, 6] # ints here but it's the same conceptually

combined_result = average_duplicates(names, result_values)

print combined_result

{"pears": 4, "apples": 1, "bananas": 8}
```

My only ideas involve multiple iterations and so far have been ugly... is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dictionary anyways

```
averages = {}
counts = {}
for name, value in zip(names, result_values):
    if name in averages:
        averages[name] += value
        counts[name] += 1
    else:
        averages[name] = value
        counts[name] = 1
for name in averages:
    averages[name] = averages[name]/float(counts[name])
```

If you're concerned with large lists, then I would replace `zip` with `izip` from itertools.

Comment: You have strange indentation in last lines.

Comment: @Constantin, That was one more typo than I thought I had. Good looking out.

Comment: Finally I can +1 this answer :)

Comment: @aaronasterling: Using `collections.defaultdict` would definitely make the code simpler.

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def averages(names, values):
    # Group the items by name.
    value_lists = defaultdict(list)
    for name, value in zip(names, values):
        value_lists[name].append(value)

    # Take the average of each list.
    result = {}
    for name, values in value_lists.iteritems():
        result[name] = sum(values) / float(len(values))
    return result

names = ["pears", "apples", "pears", "bananas", "pears"]
result_values = [2, 1, 4, 8, 6]
print averages(names, result_values)
```

Comment: @GlennMaynard: Yeah, yours is better. :) The counting loop is simpler, and you use a single, unified structure (`value_lists`) instead of two distinct but coupled variables.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the mean using a [Cumulative moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) to only iterate through the lists once:

```
from collections import defaultdict
averages = defaultdict(float)
count = defaultdict(int)

for name,result in zip(names,result_values):
    count[name] += 1
    averages[name] += (result - averages[name]) / count[name]
```

Comment: Interesting tip, I'll use it for larger data sets.

Comment: The "Cumulative moving average" will give you the same result as the standard mean so you could use it for all your data sets.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

def average_duplicates(names, values):
  pairs = sorted(zip(names, values))
  result = {}
  for key, group in itertools.groupby(pairs, key=lambda p: p[0]):
    group_values = [value for (_, value) in group]
    result[key] = sum(group_values) / len(group_values)
  return result
```

See also [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: How would it fare, performance-wise, to the other solutions? I'm interested as I may have long lists and so performance may be an issue.

Comment: @Einar, it could be faster, because `groupby` does not create a copy of data, and it could be slower because of `sorted`. I'll have to measure.

Comment: More precisely, none of these copy the data--they only create new containers holding them.  The data itself just gets new references taken.  `groupby` doesn't create a new list, but note that `zip`, `sorted` and the list comprehension for `group_values` do.

Comment: Also note that this one will probably be affected by the order of `names`: `sorted` will be much faster if it's already partially sorted than if not.

Comment: @Einar, aaronasterling's solution is fastest when number of distinct names is large. When there are a few distinct names, Glenn Maynard's solution is fastest. My solution loses to them at least 3x on large lists. This is for `Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`.

Comment: Thanks, will update with aaronasterling's solution then, as I may have a large number of distinct names and few duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def avg_list(keys, values):
...     def avg(series):
...             return sum(series) / len(series)
...     from collections import defaultdict
...     d = defaultdict(list)
...     for k, v in zip(keys, values):
...             d[k].append(v)
...     return dict((k, avg(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
... 
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     names = ["pears", "apples", "pears", "bananas", "pears"]
...     result_values = [2, 1, 4, 8, 6]
...     print avg_list(names, result_values)
... 
{'apples': 1, 'pears': 4, 'bananas': 8}
```

You can have `avg()` return `float(len(series))` if you want a floating point average.