# Average duplicate values from two paired lists in Python using NumPy

Tags: python, list, numpy, average

In the past I have faced myself [dealing with averaging two paired lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022465/average-the-duplicated-values-from-two-paired-lists-in-python) and I have used the answers provided there successfully.

However with large (more than 20,000) items the procedure is somewhat slow, and I was wondering if using NumPy would make it faster.

I start from two lists, one of floats and one of strings:

```
names = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"]
values = [1.2, 4.5, 4.3, 2.0, 5.67, 8.08, 9.01]
```

I'm trying to calculate the mean of the identical values, so that after applying it, I'd get:

```
result_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
result_values = [1.2, 4.4, 2.0, 5.67, 8.54]
```

I put two lists as a result example, but having also a list of  `(name, value)` tuples would suffice:

```
result = [("a", 1.2), ("b", 4.4), ("d", 5.67), ("e", 8.54)]
```

What's the best way to do this with NumPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With numpy you can write something yourself, or you can use groupby functionality (the rec_groupby function from matplotlib.mlab, but which is much slower. For more powerful groupby functionality, maybe look at [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/)), and I compared it with the answer of Michael Dunn with a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from matplotlib.mlab import rec_groupby

listA = [random.choice("abcdef") for i in range(20000)]
listB = [20 * random.random() for i in range(20000)]

names = np.array(listA)
values = np.array(listB)

def f_dict(listA, listB):
    d = {}

    for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
        d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

    avg = []
    for key in d:
        avg.append(sum(d[key])/len(d[key]))

    return d.keys(), avg

def f_numpy(names, values):
    result_names = np.unique(names)
    result_values = np.empty(result_names.shape)

    for i, name in enumerate(result_names):
        result_values[i] = np.mean(values[names == name])

    return result_names, result_values
```

This is the result for the three:

```
In [2]: f_dict(listA, listB)
Out[2]: 
(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'],
 [9.9003182717213765,
  10.077784850173568,
  9.8623915728699636,
  9.9790599744319319,
  9.8811096512807097,
  10.118695410115953])

In [3]: f_numpy(names, values)
Out[3]: 
(array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 
      dtype='|S1'),
 array([  9.90031827,   9.86239157,  10.07778485,   9.88110965,
         9.97905997,  10.11869541]))

In [7]: rec_groupby(struct_array, ('names',), (('values', np.mean, 'resvalues'),))
Out[7]: 
rec.array([('a', 9.900318271721376), ('b', 9.862391572869964),
       ('c', 10.077784850173568), ('d', 9.88110965128071),
       ('e', 9.979059974431932), ('f', 10.118695410115953)], 
      dtype=[('names', '|S1'), ('resvalues', '<f8')])
```

And it seems that numpy is a little bit faster for this test (and the pre-defined groupby function much slower):

```
In [32]: %timeit f_dict(listA, listB)
10 loops, best of 3: 23 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit f_numpy(names, values)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.78 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit rec_groupby(struct_array, ('names',), (('values', np.mean, 'values'),))
1 loops, best of 3: 203 ms per loop
```

Comment: So it sounds like numpy is worth it: if your script does this 150 times the dict solution would cause a ~2 second delay.

Comment: But a remark, in the timings I didn't count the conversion of the list to the numpy array. And this may compensate the little time gain with numpy (I tested it in the above case, and then f_numpy has almost the same speed: 19.3 ms). So maybe it depends on whether you have to convert the list to a numpy array each time.

Comment: As far as my tests go, I don't see an impact that large towards the conversion list -> array, but admittedly I haven't run comprehensive comparisons between the two versions.

Comment: The Numpy way is actually way slower, by orders of magnitude, if you increase the number of unique keys. Your example only has 6 unique keys. When there are more, f_dict beats numpy way out of the water.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a numpy solution is more elaborate than you need. Without doing anything fancy, I found the following to be "quick as a flash" (as in, there was no noticable wait with 20000 items in the list):

```
import random

listA = [random.choice("abcdef") for i in range(20000)]
listB = [20 * random.random() for i in range(20000)]

d = {}

for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
    d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

for key in d:
    print key, sum(d[key])/len(d[key])
```

Your milage might vary, depending on whether 20000 is a typical length for your lists, and whether you do this only a couple of times in a script or whether you're doing it hundreds/thousands of times.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, you're right: I'm doing this for about 150 times and the average length is around 20K.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution via numpy, assuming vA0 and vB0 as numpy.arrays, which are indexed by vA0.

```
import numpy as np

def avg_group(vA0, vB0):
    vA, ind, counts = np.unique(vA0, return_index=True, return_counts=True) # get unique values in vA0
    vB = vB0[ind]
    for dup in vB[counts>1]: # store the average (one may change as wished) of original elements in vA0 reference by the unique elements in vB
        vB[np.where(vA==dup)] = np.average(vB0[np.where(vA0==dup)])
    return vA, vB
```

Comment: This can be cleaned up a bit, but unique seems like the simplest method here.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late to the party, but seeing as numpy still seems to lack this feature, here is my best attempt at a pure numpy solution to achieve a grouping by key. It should be far faster than the other proposed solutions for problem sets of appreciable size. The crux here is the nifty reduceat functionality.

```
import numpy as np

def group(key, value):
    """
    group the values by key
    returns the unique keys, their corresponding per-key sum, and the keycounts
    """
    #upcast to numpy arrays
    key = np.asarray(key)
    value = np.asarray(value)
    #first, sort by key
    I = np.argsort(key)
    key = key[I]
    value = value[I]
    #the slicing points of the bins to sum over
    slices = np.concatenate(([0], np.where(key[:-1]!=key[1:])[0]+1))
    #first entry of each bin is a unique key
    unique_keys = key[slices]
    #sum over the slices specified by index
    per_key_sum = np.add.reduceat(value, slices)
    #number of counts per key is the difference of our slice points. cap off with number of keys for last bin
    key_count = np.diff(np.append(slices, len(key)))
    return unique_keys, per_key_sum, key_count


names = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"]
values = [1.2, 4.5, 4.3, 2.0, 5.67, 8.08, 9.01]

unique_keys, per_key_sum, key_count = group(names, values)
print per_key_sum / key_count
```